# Two strings by same match() method in JavaScript

Tags: jquery, regex, string, replace, match

My question is, how I match two strings by same match () Method, example given below:

*Original code:*

```
var self = $(this);
var src = self.attr('src');    
if (src.match(/category/image.jpeg)) {
    self.attr('src', src.replace("/category/","/categories/"));
}
```

**I want to match two strings like this:**

```
var self = $(this);
var src = self.attr('src');    
if (src.match(/category/image.jpeg, /category/image.png)) {
    self.attr('src', src.replace("/category/","/categories/"));
}
```

So, I made change like this `if (src.match(/category/image.jpeg, /category/image.png))`

But not working, I think it's wrong, but how to match two different strings by same Method? By my given code.

Comment: how one string can be equal to two diff strings at a time.

Comment: do you see something wrong in `.match(/category/image.jgep)`

Comment: `if (src.match(/category/image.jgep) || src.match( /category/image.png))`

Comment: @Tushar Nop............

Comment: @OAD This working but Uncaught TypeError on Console log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.match(/category/image.jgep)` is not a valid syntax to use RegEx with [`String#match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) and will throw syntax error.

To check if the string contains `.jpeg` or `.png` images, you can use

```
/category\/image\.(?:jpeg|png)$/
```

Use [`RegExp#test`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) instead of [`String#match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) to check if the string follows the pattern.

**Code:**

```
var regex = /category\/image\.(?:jpeg|png)$/i;
if (regex.test('src')) {
    self.attr('src', src.replace("/category/","/categories/"));
}
```

---

To replace `/category/` for all the images, you can use [attribute contains selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) with [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-function) with callback.

```
$('img[src*="/category/"]').attr('src', function(ind, oldSrc) {
    return oldSrc.replace("/category/", "/categories/");
});
```

Comment: This working as my question : `if (src.match(/category/image.jpg) || src.match( /category/image.png))`

Comment: @Aabira [It throws error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid flags supplied to RegExp constructor 'image'"](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/yLoq8oLz/)

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are wanting is a regex that matches any png or jpeg file in the category directory, in which case this would be the regex you would want to use:

```
/\/category\/.*\.(jpeg|png)/
```

And in code:

```
var self = $(this);
var src = self.attr('src');    
if (src.match(/\/category\/.*\.(jpeg|png)/)) {
    self.attr('src', src.replace("/category/","/categories/"));
}
```

Comment: Is possible like this: `if (src.match(/category/image.jpg) || src.match( /category/image.png)) ` This working but Uncaught TypeError

Answer (score 1):

Here's the regex you need

```
 /category(\/image\.(?:jpe?g|png))/gi
```

**Regex101 Demo: https://regex101.com/r/eN6gW1/1**

Example

```
var regex = /category(\/image\.(?:jpe?g|png))/gi;

var self = $(this);
var src = self.attr('src');    
self.attr('src', src.replace(regex, 'categories$1'));
```

**JSFiddle Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/qjyukz4c/4/**

Comment: Is possible like this: `if (src.match(/category/image.jpg) || src.match( /category/image.png)) ` This working but Uncaught TypeError

Comment: @Aabira `src.match(/category\/image\.jpg/) || src.match(/category\/image\.png/)`

Answer (score 1):

try this 
**NOTE:** this is with quotes

```
if(src.match('/category/image.jgep') || src.match( '/category/image.png')) {
    self.attr('src', src.replace("/category/","/categories/"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

HTML

```
<img src="category.image.jpeg">
<img src="category.image.png">
<img src="category.image.gif">
```

JS

```
var $img = $('img'),
  baseStr = 'category.image',
  ext = ['.jpeg', '.png'],
  aryMatchStr = $.map(ext, function(item) {
    return baseStr + item;
  });

$.map($img, function(item, index) {
  var $item = $(item),
    src = $item.attr('src');

    for(var i = 0, len = aryMatchStr.length; i < len; i++){
      if(src.match(aryMatchStr[i])){
        $item.attr('src', src.replace(/category/, 'categories'));
      }
    }
});
```

Result

```
<img src="categories.image.jpeg">
<img src="categories.image.png">
<img src="category.image.gif">
```